# How do I view all of a user's orders in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have made a simple Rails app where users are able to add orders they have made to an Order model. I used Devise and I have been able to work out how to only allow a user to delete and edit their on orders. Now I would like for a user to be able to view all of the orders they have created. A user has many orders and orders belong to users.

I'd like to be able to go to `localhost:3000/users/1/orders` and see all of their orders.

Here is my current orders controller:

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
    before_action :find_order, only: [:edit, :destroy, :update, :show]

    def index
        @orders = Order.all.order("created_at DESC")
    end

    def new
        @order = current_user.orders.build
    end

    def update
        if @order.update(order_params)
            redirect_to root_path
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end

    def show
    end

    def create
        @order = current_user.orders.build(order_params)

        if @order.save
            redirect_to root_path
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    def edit
    end

    def destroy
        @order.destroy
        redirect_to root_path
    end

    private

        def order_params
            params.require(:order).permit(:start_point, :restaurant_location, :customer_location, :fee)
        end

        def find_order
            @order = Order.find(params[:id])
        end

end
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This was also posted on Reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/rails/comments/9xsdge/how_do_i_view_all_of_a_users_orders_in_rails/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would set it up like so:

```
resources :users, only: [] do
  resources :orders, module: :users, only: :index
end
```

This routes `/users/:user_id/orders` to `Users::OrdersController#index`.

Using the `module` option is a nifty trick that lets you disambiguate between nested and non nested resources. Meaning that it will not effect your existing orders index.

Creating the controller itself is very straight forward:

```
# app/controllers/users/orders_controller.rb
module Users
  class OrdersController
    # GET /users/:user_id/orders
    def index
      @user = User.includes(:orders).find(params[:user_id])
      @orders = @user.orders
    end
  end
end
```

And a just create a view:

```
# app/views/users/orders/index.html.erb
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
       <th>id</th>
       <th>created_at</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @orders.each do |order|%>
    <tr>
      <td><%= order.id %></td>
      <td><%= order.created_at %></td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Remember that partials are your friend if you want to share view code with the "normal" index.

Comment: I don't understand... I'm new to Rails (and programming) so bear with me. Your example has an orders controller within a users module here:

`# app/controllers/users/orders_controller.rb`

Does this mean i generate a new orders controller? Or do I just add the users module to my existing orders controller?

Comment: No - its a separate controller and you don't need to generate it since you already have the code.

Comment: Okay, this worked! Although I needed to make sure the controller class was inheriting from `ApplicationController`. Thanks!